How to add custom headers to Mailgun emails (via API)?
I'm sending emails via Mailgun (on my Deno server), and whatever I do, I cannot pass custom headers - they are simply ignored.
Specifically, I'm trying to pass List-Unsubscribe and List-Unsubscribe-Post, but I added other headers too, just to test. Nothing is visible in Mailgun logs.
For this code:
await mailgun.send({
        to: mailgunData.email,
        from: mailgunData.from,
        subject: mailgunData.subject,
        template: ReminderEmailTemplate.Projects,
        "v:projectsLink": `${getBaseUrl()}/projects`,
        "v:projectStartLink": `${getBaseUrl()}/project-start`,
        "v:jobsLink": `${getBaseUrl()}/jobs`,
        "v:fullName": mailgunData.full_name,
        "h:List-Unsubscribe": "<http://lists.domain.tld/newsletter>, <mailto:newsletter-request@domain.tld?subject=unsubscribe>",
        "h:List-Unsubscribe-Post": "List-Unsubscribe=One-Click",
        "h:Precedence": "bulk",
        "h:Priority": "normal",
        "h:X-Mailgun-Tag": "newsletter",
        "h:Feedback-ID": "1234:newsletter:mailgun",
        "h:X-Mailgun-Dkim": "yes",
        "h:something": "something",
        "h:Reply-To": "something@something.com",
})

None of the headers get passed, only to, from, subject, template, and variables prefixed with v:.
I would appreciate the help - almost seems like some config is blocking headers from being passed.

The package you're using for mailgun.send may intentionally support only some of the functionality of the Mailgun API. Using an HTTP library to directly query the API may give better results. I'm able to use the h:List-Unsubscribe-Post and h:List-Unsubscribe keys successfully.
